# SSTable loader streaming failed giving java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to use sstableloader to stream data to a Cassandra database, which is in fact in the same node. It used to work when i was using DSE 2.2 but when i upgraded it to DSE 4.5 and made all the relevant changes in the cassandra.yaml file, it stopped working and now it is throwing an error like this:

```
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of demo/test_yale/demo-test_yale-jb-2-Data.db demo/test_yale/demo-test_yale-jb-1-Data.db to [/127.0.0.1]
Streaming session ID: 02225ef0-1c17-11e4-a1ea-5f2d4f6a32c1
progress: [/127.0.0.1 1/2 (88%)] [total: 88% - 2147483647MB/s (avg: 14MB/s)]ERROR 16:36:29,029 [Stream #02225ef0-1c17-11e4-a1ea-5f2d4f6a32c1] Streaming error occurred
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Channels.java:78)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Channels.java:98)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Channels.java:61)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:174)
        at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFChunk.writeCompressedHeader(LZFChunk.java:77)
        at com.ning.compress.lzf.ChunkEncoder.encodeAndWriteChunk(ChunkEncoder.java:132)
        at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFOutputStream.writeCompressedBlock(LZFOutputStream.java:203)
        at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFOutputStream.write(LZFOutputStream.java:97)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamWriter.write(StreamWriter.java:151)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamWriter.write(StreamWriter.java:101)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:59)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:42)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:45)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:383)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:363)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 WARN 16:36:29,032 [Stream #02225ef0-1c17-11e4-a1ea-5f2d4f6a32c1] Stream failed
Streaming to the following hosts failed:
[/127.0.0.1]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
```

I have even tried assigning actual ip address of the node for the listen_address, broadcast_address, and rpc_address in the cassandra.yaml file but the same error occurs.

Can anyone be of assistance please?

Comment: Any errors in the nodes system.log?  You could try turning off internode compression in the cassandra.yaml to see if that is causing a problem for some reason.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking at your system.log as specified in cassandra/conf/logback.xml, as suggested by Zanson.

In my case the issue was simply with exhausting disk space on the node:

```
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/xx.xx.xx.xx] 2016-08-02 10:50:31,125 StreamSession.java:505 - [Stream #8420bfa0-589c-11e6-9512-235b1f79cf1b] Streaming error occurred
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(RandomAccessFile.java:525) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
```